# Using an ExtJS grid with vertical header columns

Tags: extjs, gridpanel

So right now I have an ExtJS GridPanel that is laid out in the following manner:

```
|Header 1|Header 2|Header 3|Header4|
|Data 1  |Data 2  |Data 3  |Data 4 |
|Data 1  |Data 2  |Data 3  |Data 4 |
```

What I should like to do is have it displayed in the following manner:

```
|Header 1|Data 1|Data 1|
|Header 2|Data 2|Data 2|
|Header 3|Data 3|Data 3|
|Header 4|Data 4|Data 4|
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this WITHOUT dropping the GridPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [PivotGrid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.grid.PivotGrid).

Example [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/pivotgrid/countries.html).

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the PivotGrid was introduced in ExtJS 3.3.0 and I am forced to use 3.0.0. I tried porting it but no luck thus far. I'll mark you as the answer since it answers my question and is the best solution. Unfortunately for me I'll need to find something else.

Comment: Ah. That's a pain. Have you looked at overriding `GridView`'s `doRender`? It looks like you could get "most" of the way there by hacking that, for a given value of most.

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/GridView.html#prop-Ext.grid.GridView